# Parenting an object in PyQt causes the object to be owned by Qt instead of PyQt. What are the consequences?

Tags: qt, pyqt, parent-child

In the `QObject.__init__(self, Parent=None)` documentation it states:

The parent argument, if not None, causes self to be owned by Qt instead of PyQt.

What does it mean to be owned by Qt instead of PyQt? Does this have effects on behavior that I should be aware of when developing a PyQt application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It is. It have **Effects** to before create any object in PyQt application. If we set parent QWidget None, I can be tell this QWidget is top-level window. I will try explain;

***"Parent Widget equivalent like frame of windows"***

[image: Picture 1: Frame of user interface]
Parent Widget of QMainWindow  is none. Then, owned by Qt instead of PyQt (or easy word **root**). Parent Widget of QWidget (in red) is QMainWindow, Then geometry reference by QMainWindow. Parent Widget of QPushButton is QWidget (Green), Then geometry reference by QWidget (Green). And all widget as same ...

So, QMainWindow have fully control widget in your child. For example, If self delete, All child will follow delete too. etc.

But, If we set Parent Widget of QWidget (in red) is None, that mean  this QWidget like new window. Like this picture;

[image: 2 top-level window]

For now, we have 2 top-level window. But QWidget have independent with QMainWindow. If self delete, All child will follow delete too but not outside QMainWindow. Outside QWidget not delete. So, some application have create many widget, but it will has main widget in main menu to control child.

**Not only frame of windows, It just Example & Comparison.**

---

Regards,